# Hive query to replace only the first occurrence of a substring

Tags: regex, string, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I need to replace the first occurrence of a substring from the given string.
Eg If the string is `"My name is Adam"` and I want to replace the first `"a"` with `"@"`.
So my desired output is `"My n@me is Adam"`.
In MySQL, there is a function `regexp_replace` which has an optional parameter `occurrence` to specify how many occurrences to replace. But unfortunately, that optional parameter is not present in the hive function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

```
hive> select regexp_replace('My name is Adam','^(.*?)a','$1@');
OK
My n@me is Adam
Time taken: 0.061 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Pattern `'^(.*?)a'` means:

```
  ^ - the beginning of the string
.*? - any character (.) zero or more times (*) not greedy (?)
 () - remember group, we will refer it in the replacement string as $1
  a - 'a' character literally
```

Replacement string `'$1@'` means:

```
$1 - group number one in the pattern (everything before 'a')
 @ - '@' character literally
```

You can debug regexp here: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)